# Tkinter window stops registering Motion events after hovering other windows

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have set up a window just to register mouse motion. This works well if there are no other windows open behind it. The Motion events will naturally stop rolling in when I move the mouse mouse outside the window, and will continue being registered when I hover back over the window.

However, when I hover the cursor out of the Tkinter window and over another window, the Tkinter window won't register any Motion events when I hover back to it. Am I missing some important detail, or is it a bug? If it's a bug, is there a known work-around?

```
import Tkinter as tk


class CursorWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, width=640, height=400):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Sample application')

        self.root.minsize(width, height)
        self.root.maxsize(width, height)

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.root, width=width, height=height, background='black')
        self.pack()
        self.bind("<Motion>", self.cb)

    def cb(self, event):
        print "%d, %d" % (event.x, event.y)

w = CursorWindow()
w.mainloop()
```

This is on OSX 10.8.3, Python 2.7.2

**EDIT:** The workaround, in this simple case, is to force the Frame to grab focus no matter the position of the mouse (as though it were a button down + motion event) with Frame.grab_set(). This way, the window will never stop delivering event as long as it's active. As far as I'm concerned, this is still a dirty trick, and if anyone has any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Can you try binding `<Enter>` to see if you're getting that event? If you don't get `<Enter>`, Tk won't know that your window is the one that's supposed to get `<Motion>` events, so that's what we have to track down. If you get `<Enter>` but still don't get `<Motion>`, it's something different.

Comment: Also, note that although Tk documents `<Motion>`, Tkinter does not, and the Effbot documentation (and the O'Reilly book) specifically say there is no such event. I wouldn't put too much stock in that ([Shipman's Tkinter reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-types.html) specifically lists `<Motion>`), but it may be a sign that people aren't using it too much and aren't noticing bugs…

Comment: If it's documented in the tk documents (and it is) then it almost certainly is supported by Tkinter. The only way for it to not be supported is if Tkinter explicitly disabled it, and there's no reason why they would do that.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Yes, that's why I wouldn't put too much stock in it. When the Effbot documentation says you can't do something that Tk says you can, it's usually just because it's out of date.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow Philip. You should propose your workaround as just another answer and let the voting sort them. After a while you can judge which answer is better and accept it (even your's if it fit best). You might be interested to look around [welcome page](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: One relatively easy workaround you might consider trying: Install a later version of Tcl/Tk. (Make sure to get an Aqua Cocoa build.) Python.org [recommends ActiveTcl 8.5.14](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#activetcl-8-5-14) for Python 2.7.5 on OS X 10.8, although you may want either the latest 8.5 (which is still 8.5.14.0 today, but could change for future readers) or the latest 8.x (which is 8.6.0.0 today; I'm not sure whether 8.6 will work with pre-built Tkinter binaries, but you can try it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a bit of testing, I think this is a bug in the version of Tkinter that came with Python 2.7 and earlier.

With Apple's Python 2.7.2 and Apple's Tcl/Tk 8.5.9 on OS X 10.8.3, I have the exact same problem. And, as I suspected, it's caused by `<Enter>` usually not being delivered until I click in the window, which means Tk doesn't know to deliver the `<Motion>` events to the window.

The same thing happens with Apple's Python 2.6.7 and 2.5.6, Homebrew 2.7.3, Python.org 2.7.3, and Homebrew 2.7.5.

However, with Homebrew 3.3.1, Python.org 3.3.2, and a local build off trunk, with everything else the same (except for changing your `import` and `print`, of course), everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid Python 3 is out of the question. I can confirm the Enter behavior. I would upvote, but I don't have enough karma yet.

Comment: I tried looking through bug reports and release notes and can't see anything about this fix, so… hopefully someone else can find it and write a proper answer. (Just knowing that there _was_ a fix doesn't help you unless you can upgrade to 3.3; knowing exactly what the fix _does_ might tell us how to work around the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a bug or quirk in how OSX handles events. OSX and the Tk event loop don't mesh very well and there's a lot of voodoo under the hood to try and make it all work. It's not entirely surprising that something like this doesn't work.

For what it's worth, tracking motion when a button is pressed seems to work just fine (eg: `<B1-Motion>`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a likely explanation. Indeed, B1-Motion works as it should.